# Информация о интернет подключении компьютера

Tags: c++-cli

Задача: получить информацию о интернет подключении комьютера(ip адрес, порт и т.п.) и записать её в label`ы. Какие есть предложения? Если возможно, с примерами, пожалуйста, я в этом слабоват.

Comment: произвольный сервер в интернете вряд ли просто так узнает, какого цвета у Вас системный блок. Но клиент теоретически это может узнать (включить камеру). Но как тут поможет dcom...

Comment: @KoVadim Клиент и Сервер находятся относительно рядом, они в одной локальной сети

Comment: теоретически, если везде windows и есть админские права, то можно воспользоваться WMI

Comment: @KoVadim Не могли бы Вы показать пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--networking  но я не уверен, что я полностью понимаю всю задачу.

Comment: @KoVadim Да, я наверно, действительно не до конца понятно выразился.  Я изменил пост.